font style italic is not working in windowsOS but working in MacOS
Hi I am Working in nextjs project, there we using font-family as TT norms pro.
here font-style: italic is not working in Windows OS but it is working in MAC OS. Below I have given my code


import localFont from 'next/font/local';
import React from 'react';
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'Test Working',
  icons: {
    icon: favicon.src,
  },
};

const ttnormsProFont = localFont({
  src: '../public/fonts/TTNormsPro.ttf',
  display: 'swap',
});

export default function RootLayout({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={ttnormsProFont.className}>
      <body className="dark">
        <ConfigureAmplifyClientSide />
        <Toaster />
        <ReduxProvider>{children}</ReduxProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



I dont know why it is not working. Could you please help me to resolve it! Thank you

You haven't mentioned how you installed/implemented the font so I don't have a clear solution here. But still make sure there is an Italic version of it and you have imported it.

I have updated the code and it is a local font

Try adding the fonts like
{       path: './Roboto-BoldItalic.woff2',       weight: '700',       style: 'italic',     },

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
